# How can I form this sentence better?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, sentence

I am trying to formulate the following sentence:

"-also they can focus on research work (instead of fighting with technical limitations and problems)"

However, I am not quite happy with its current form.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As non native English speaker I learned that you probably cannot start a sentence with 'also' in the way you did. You don't give much context of the sentence which makes it hard to correct it. Typically it's not a good writing style to use parenthesis a lot either. 
My suggestion would be:

> furthermore, they can put their main focus on research rather than the technical limitations and problems.